# Laravel + Lighthouse (GraphQL) custom mutation validation

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Earlier I used pure graphQL for Laravel and I didn't have a problem with it, because the whole validation could be done in files in ../GraphQL/mutations/. However, I have now started using the lighthouse and many things are done differently. For example, I have this mutation:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(
    name: String @rules(apply: ["required", "min:2"])
    age: Int!
  ): User @create
}
```

How can I add my own validation here? For example, I would like the user's age to be at least 10 years back from the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Following the lighthouse validation in [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/security/validation.html#single-arguments) you first you add `@validator` to the schema.

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(
    name: String
    age: Int!
  ): User @create @validator
}
```

Then you create that validator with `php artisan lighthouse:validator CreateUserValidator`.
On the file, you do the **before** laravel validation [rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules).

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Validators;

use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Validation\Validator;

class CreateUserValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * Return the validation rules.
     *
     * @return array<string, array<mixed>>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'min:2'
            ],
            'age' => [
                'required',
                'date',
                'before:-10 years'
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```